# Emacs: gethash doesn't see key in hashtable

Tags: emacs, elisp, hashtable

I evaluated the following elisp code in ielm:

```
(setq foo-hash (make-hash-table))

(puthash "location" "house" foo-hash)

(defun foo-start ()
  (interactive)
  (message (gethash "location" foo-hash)))
```

However when i run `(foo-start)` or `(gethash "location" foo-hash)` i get only `nil` echoed. Entering just `foo-hash` in ielm echoes: `#s(hash-table size 65 test eql rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ("location" "house"))`

Is that a bug or i am doing something wrong?

Emacs version: 24.0.95.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hash tables in elisp use `eql` for comparison by default.  Strings won't be equal with `eql` unless they're the same object.  You probably want to use `equal`, which compares the contents of the strings.  Create your hash table with this:

```
(make-hash-table :test 'equal)
```